# How to format timestamp to a calendar format date?

Tags: javascript, devextreme

I'm using [devExtreme dxScheduler](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Scheduler/SimpleArray/AngularJS/Light/) and i'm trying to display meetings after fetching them from api, the problem is that i can't recreate the original date format ("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ") since i'm getting the dates as timestamp.

Here is how it's stores :

```
var startDate = moment("2021-05-24T16:30:00.000Z").valueOf()
// 1621873800000
```

Here is what i'm trying to do to recreate the format:

```
var startDate = moment(new Date(startDate)).format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ")
 //"2021-05-24T07:30:00+03:00"
```

Notice that the original date ("2021-05-24T16:30:00.000Z") and the formatted date ("2021-05-24T07:30:00+03:00")  are different ...hence the calendar do not displays them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the date is being converted into your local timezone, thus the difference. You may need to add [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) to be able to get the timezone back in to recreate it to the format you need. Also consider adding `utc()` before the format to bring it to Zulu time.

Answer (score 1):

**Fix 1**

I see from the DevExtreme page that it needs to be displayed within this format:

```
currentDate: new Date(2021, 4, 27)
```

Maybe you need to format it before adding it like this:

```js
var check = moment("2021-05-24T16:30:00.000Z", 'YYYY/MM/DD');

var month = check.format('M');
var day   = check.format('D');
var year  = check.format('YYYY');

console.log(month,day,year);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

And then in your dxScheduler add the property like this:

```
currentDate: new Date(year, month, day);
```

**Fix 2**

If that's not the problem, you can install moment-timezone

```
var a = moment.utc("2013-11-18 11:55").tz("Asia/Taipei");
var b = moment.utc("2013-11-18 11:55").tz("America/Toronto");

a.format(); // 2013-11-18T19:55:00+08:00
b.format(); // 2013-11-18T06:55:00-05:00

a.utc().format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55Z
b.utc().format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55Z
```

In this example, you first create moment.utc("2013-11-18 11:55") object in UTC, and then change its timezone to specified. This also works if you create the object in your default timezone: moment("2013-11-18 11:55").

Note that created moments have equal UTC time because these moments were created in a default timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that displaying a calendar event with DevExtreme requires only to use regular date object.... so no need to do anything spacial.